# OpenStack Autopilot landscape setup stuck in check 3 - Minimum nodes

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to setup openstack with Autopilot using the tutorial at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot

I have setup 4 x HP DL380 servers (Dual CPU , IPMI, 32GB , Disk 1: 72GB , Disk 2: 146GB) .  I managed to Commission all the 4 servers in MAAS and deployed the landscape on one of them through autopilot.

In Landscape, I keep getting an error for the number of servers, it says the minimum 3 servers should be commissioned in MAAS, where as I already have 4, and added another VM (Vmware VM) as additional unit.  with 5 servers still it is stuck.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Oops, my previous "answer" should have been a comment, thank you for clarifying. Can you please double check that you have the correct MAAS credentials registered in Landscape? If so, please grab /var/log/landscape-server/job-handler.log and post it on pastebin.ubuntu.com with a link here

Answer (score 1):

What state are the servers in MAAS? You will want them to be Ready. Can you share a screenshot of the node listing page?